# Easiest way to present AppEngine data for user editing

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Are there any standard utilities in which you can just offer a class (`db.Model`) to the user and for them to be able to do all the standard insert, delete,update functions on it? I really don't want to have to write one for each type I have. I know this makes it "more powerful" but right now I'm after quicker proof of concept stuff.

Comment: Consider using django or Flask instead. Both work considerably well with GAE.

Comment: wtforms can do some model-form-user-model stuff. http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.3/ext.html#module-wtforms.ext.appengine